# Unable to launch EC2 instance from browser-based SSH from macbook but Windows machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have launched EC2 instance successfully. I am trying to connect to it using "EC2 Instance Connect ( browser-based SSH connection)" within aws-console.

From Windows machine I am able to connect to EC2 and can see prompt.
But somehow when I try from Macbook not working. It's opening new window with below message :

**There was a problem setting up the instance connection**
*The connection has been closed because the server is taking too long to respond. This is usually caused by network problems, such as a spotty wireless signal, or slow network speeds. Please check your network connection and try again or contact your system administrator.*

I have windows and macbook machine connected to same wifi. I run internet speed test and both machines have almost similar high speed connection.

Comment: You might have a VPN connected on the Macbook

Comment: Well, it's a brand new Macbook setup today. I do not remember setting up VPN unless it has it's own by default ?

Comment: you can visit https://whatismyipaddress.com/ and check if both Windows and Mac are displaying the same ip. If they are then it is browser or any other software which blocking the connection

Comment: I can login to same EC2 using Terminal with SSH command using .pem from both machines.

Comment: looks like this has been flagged already https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=872136&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you use browser-based connection in different OSes, with different browsers obviously.
This browser-based connection is based on Java application that is forbidden in many modern browsers.
If for any reason you still need browser-based connection, then tune your browser to work with it. Some details are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstarts/latest/vmlaunch/step-2-connect-to-instance.html#browser).

For real life cases it's better to use SSH outside of your browser.